# I am making a quiz and I ran js code through shiftedit and got the following error: 'answerValue' used out of scope: lin 15

Tags: javascript

I am making a quiz and I ran the js code ...
`if (isNaN(answerValue)) { answerValue = 0...`
through shiftedit and got the following error:

> 'answerValue' used out of scope: line 15

```
 function answerScore(qName) {
  var radiosNo = document.getElementsByName(qName);
  for (var i = 0, length = radiosNo.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radiosNo[i].checked) {
      // do something with radiosNo
      var answerValue = Number(radiosNo[i].value);
    }
  }
  // change NaNs to zero
  if (isNaN(answerValue)) {
    answerValue = 0;
  }
  return answerValue;
}
```

Comment: You have declare `answerValue ` in if condition and you are trying to access it outside also

Comment: Awesome! thanks :)

Comment: added an answer for the same you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says `error: 'answerValue' used out of scope: line 15`.
You have declared `answerValue` in `if` condition and you are trying to access it outside `if` also. Declaring it in function scope will solve your problem

```
function answerScore(qName) {
 var radiosNo = document.getElementsByName(qName);
 var answerValue  = null;
 for (var i = 0, length = radiosNo.length; i < length; i++) {
 if (radiosNo[i].checked) {
  // do something with radiosNo
  answerValue = Number(radiosNo[i].value);
 }
}
// change NaNs to zero

if (isNaN(answerValue)) {
answerValue = 0; 
}
return answerValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first define `var answerValue = 0`, than iterate over the elements using [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and instead of checking `isNaN(answerValue)` you most use do [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Code:

```
function answerScore(qName) {
  var answerValue = 0;

  document
    .querySelectorAll(qName)
    .forEach(el => {
      if (el.checked) {
        answerValue = Number(el.value);
      }
    });

  return !Number.isNaN(answerValue) ? answerValue : 0;
}
```